# kb2744908 not found when installing Windows Phone 8 SDK

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have Visual Studio 2012 Pro and Windows 8 Pro. I went to install the Windows 8 SDK, and it installed fine on one of my computers, on which I installed the SDK before installing the Visual Studio 2012 Update 1. But on my second computer, where I installed the Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 before the SDK, I got the following error: KB2744908 Element not found.
Not sure if I would worry about this, or not.
I've attached a screenshot, so you can see the issue. Thanks!
[image: kb2744908 not found]

Comment: Doesn't explicitly look like it failed, just that it wants to restart your computer. Possibly to apply KB2744908.

Comment: I've searched for KB2744908, but with no luck. Do you happen to know what/where it is?
I've restarted the computer now, and I'm letting the install finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have fixed itself. After rebooting and allowing the installer to finish after reboot, the SDK works fine. I have successfully created, edited, built, and deployed an application (albeit it was very simple) using the SDK.